# csvURL: Some of my series names say "undefined"

Tags: highcharts

I'm using Highcharts csvURL to import a .csv file and create a line graph. The points all seem fine, but many of my series titles are undefined. My client has 22 series. I wonder if there is a limit. I'm using the example code from highcharts:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    data: {
        csvURL: 'Ozone-4th-Highest-8hr-Front.csv'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Ozone 4th Highest 8-hr Concentration Wasatch Front'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: '(Ozone PPM)'
        }
    }
});
```

Here is what my csv looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Part of a line with hash is interpreted as a comment:

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/ts/modules/data.src.ts#L1121

To avoid that, you can use a quote:

```
<pre id="csv" style="display:none">Year,Annual mean,"#5 year mean"
1880,-0.31,
...</pre>
```

---

**Live example:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/a8e9yg0x/

Answer (score 0):

My client had hashtags in her series names. Once I removed them, csvURL worked as expected. Now I need to learn how to keep the hashtags without breaking the script!